# TestContainers-OracleContainer, init sql file that calls another sql file with @filename.sql by using sqlplus in the container

Tags: sql, oracle, testcontainers

When i'm using

```
private final static OracleContainer oracleContainer = new OracleContainer("gvenzl/oracle-xe:18.4.0-slim");
```

`oracleContainer.withInitScript("init.sql");`

with init.sql

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=XEPDB1;
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = "DD-MON-YYYY";
@scripts/init_ddl.sql ;
```

I get this error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: instruction SQL non valide
```

in the line of @scripts/init_ddl.sql ;

How can i run my init sql with **sqlplus** to call another sql file with @ in java code ?

Thank you